# TextView in dialog not getting aligned at top?

Tags: android, textview, android-dialog

I have a dialog which has a header - textview. But the problem is the textview is getting aligned at the bottom of the layout.
I want it to be center_vertical.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:minWidth="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:text="Enter OTP"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat"
        android:gravity="top" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvHeader"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your code looks ok, please clean and rebuild project

Comment: just remove the second `LinearLayout`

Comment: It tried all these, but it does not work

Comment: kindly post your java code and screen shot as well! May be i am having solution for you.

Comment: There is nothing in the Java code.
Just a class which extends Dialog. and the default constructors of the Dialog.

Comment: @Panda show us screen shot, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the title of the dialog was taking up the space. Even if I was not setting up any text for it.
I removed the title by:
thisDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

before setContentView and the extra space got removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the nested `LinearLayout` and format your xml file properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter OTP"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:minWidth="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter OTP"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

please try this

Comment: there is nothing that I am doing in the code. 
I am not at all touching the layout params in the code.